# Exclude node from XPATH results

Tags: xpath

I try to extract each text() from within the below div tags, but without the text() in between the a tag.

**I used this with no success:**

```
//div[@class="availability"]/*[not(self::a)]/text()
```

**This is the html**

```
<div class="availability">
   Available. Delivered from UK <br><a href="test.com">Click for more</a>
</div>

<div class="availability">
   Available. Delivered from HK <br><a href="test.com">Click for more</a>
</div>

<div class="availability">
   Available. Delivered from USA <br><a href="test.com">Click for more</a>
</div>

<div class="availability">
   Available. Delivered from DE <br><a href="test.com">Click for more</a>
</div>
```

Thanks for guiding me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//div[@class="availability"]/text()`